# Is there a Bash to POSIX 1003.2(a) transpiler?

Tags: bash, shell-script, posix

I've got a program I've written in bash that uses a number of bashisms. I know there's `checkbashism` and `shellcheck` and bash's `--posix` which are great for manual review. But what I really want is something like python's [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) and I'm assuming this exists (if not I'll probably write it).

Essentially I want to continue writing my program in modern bash but also have a build script that runs something like this:

```
$ bash2posix myprogram.sh > myprogram-compat.sh
```

and it would "fix" what it can and balk at you if there's things it cannot. I haven't been able to find any evidence of this existing, does anyone know of anything? Thanks.

Edit: I'm pretty sure this can be done. There's usually rather expensive equivalents to a lot of bashisms. String replacement for instance (`${//}`) can be done with a `printf` builtin using the precision operator (`.`) to "search" the string for a given suffix. Then you can test the length of a replacement command to see if you "found" it and then re-constitute a new string with the replacement. Is that efficient? no, of course not, but totally possible.

Comment: I don't think there _can_ be such a translator. Also note that running `bash` with `--posix` in no way _disables_ all extensions that `bash` normally introduces.

Comment: Perhaps shellcheck could be of use? Change the sh-bang line from bash to sh and see what falls out?

Comment: POSIX-correctness is also a matter of using the right commands with the right parameters. I recently witnessed an assumed "posixly correct" script that used `stat`.

Comment: I mean 1003.2 and 1003.2a posix ... not all of it.

Comment: @Kusalananda sure it can be done. There isn't any input -> output mapping (as in, a program) that can be written in bash that can't also be written in say, busyboxes 1003.2(a) compliant dash.

Comment: @kristopolous how would you deal with associative arrays? Those are supported by bash but not by POSIX sh. There are various other things like that. This is nowhere near as simple as you seem to be hoping it is. Your tool would essentially have to understand the entire logic of the script and then rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: associative arrays could be done through some syntax with magic strings __associative_varname_key=value ...

Comment: I suppose it could be done (Turing machines and all that). If it could be done sanely is a completely different question. You could emulate arrays and associative arrays with `eval` and funny variable names. Recursive functions with local variables would also be interesting, but perhaps they could be emulated with arrays indexed by the recursion level. Could `${var:n:m}` be constructed from `${var%word}` and friends? You couldn't have `/dev/tcp` without an external tool though, and you'd need to include your own regex engine for `[[ =~ ]]`.

Comment: But really, do you think it would be _useful_? Is there some machine where you just have a standard POSIX sh, but no possibility to use `awk` or Lua or simple purpose-built C programs? I would mention Perl and Python, but they're probably too heavy, since if they're not, you could just compile Bash itself, or some ksh variant which I think mostly have the features Bash does (because they were borrowed from there).

Comment: I've got an immediate use for it and I expected it to already exist, with perhaps a few incompatible caveats.  100% mapping for everything will be quite challenging and may not be possible but an ~80% mapping doesn't really sound like much work (with a very handwaving definition of 80%)

Comment: @ilkkachu `bosh` implements `local` for good reasons, programming is hard without local variables. Recursive functions with own argument lists are already in the Bourne Shell and in POSIX.

Comment: Note also that if you're trying to do this for _portability_ you have to take the tools that the script _uses_ into account, and make the "portable" script implement portable workarounds for non-standard tools  used in the script, as well as for extensions used with standard tools, such as `mv -t`.

Comment: @schily, dash and busybox sh seen to have `local` too. Not that none of that matters if they're aiming at POSIX sh. Unless it's going to be added there some time soon, that is.

Comment: @ilkkachu The `local` builtin has been added to dash on a wish from the Linux distros that started to replace `/bin/sh` by `dash` and this was also requested for `bosh` 4 years ago, when someone checked whether `bosh` could be used for `/bin/sh` on `Gentoo`. Note that 2 years ago, there was a discussion on POSIX https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=767 whether to add `local`, but this did not lead to a final decision, since some people believed that there are too few common features in the various implementations. I believe, the implementations deliver enough overlap for usability.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done. At least not 100%.

I have written `env_parallel.dash` and `env_parallel.bash` from GNU Parallel. (https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/src/env_parallel.dash and https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/src/env_parallel.bash)

You cannot convert `env_parallel.bash` to `env_parallel.dash` because `typeset -f myfunc` (show the body of a function) has no equivalent in `dash`.

Comment: this is so far the only exception I can't find a straightforward fix for. The almquist parser still stores the text in the funcnode list so that set +x can show it but since there's a separation between the vars and funcs in the C code, the variable introspection tools can't really be "tricked" to showing functions - it's a different datastructure ... I'm still not willing to claim it isn't possible. I'd need to get the code to traverse the funcnode linked list and sequentially dump the ->text entries.  It'd certainly be a hack ... but this is shell scripting, it's all a hack.

Comment: @kristopolous I will be happy if you can prove me wrong.

Comment: `dash` has several problems in POSIX compatibility. A major one is missing support for multi byte characters. `bosh` on the other side supports `type -F` as a replacement for the `ksh`-sm `typeset -f`.